# Teamcity execute on 1 of 2 conditions being true

Tags: java, continuous-integration, teamcity-9.0, teamcity-8.0

I am in the process of migrating the code base to Java 11 from Java 8. So I already had a build step for Java 8, and now I introduced one for Java 11.

I want Java 8 to be used for the master and release branch, and use Java 11 for every other branch. The problem is that for the Java 8 part, I would want it to be executed when **one** of the two conditions is met (branch name does not contain master, branch name does not contain release).
How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Digging around I found that this is not officially supported;

The 2 ways to go about it would be :

1. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html#Reporting+Build+Statistics and
2. Using "matches", which conveniently accepts a regular expression